# OpenAPI in Jetbrains Aqua fail to fetch

Tags: openapi, aqua

I have build a Openapi v3 specification for an api I have running locally. When I open up the GUI and select try it out an execute any request I always get Failed to Fetch.

I have tried accessing it from curl, a web browser as well as the HTTP Client in Aqua and have had no issues.